# Angular Material 2 Custom Data Table Row Component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a number of regular HTML tables that I would like to convert to Material 2 tables. They use custom row components like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of rows" trainingTopic [row]="r">                
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The row component selector is like this: `tr[trainingTopic]`

And the template is just td elements:

```
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
```

I'm trying to convert these to the Material 2 table, which I have working for basic stuff, but not with custom rows. I'm trying to avoid breaking everything out into the cells since there's alot of code that would have to moved around.

Doing:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="reportDataSource">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="command">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Command </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"></mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        <my-row-component>
        </my-row-component>
    </mat-row>
```

Won't create my component. I get the headers and empty rows. Trying to remove any of the cdkColumn, row def attributes, or mat-cell components causes it to throw errors at runtime. Is there any way to use my existing components?